# <a> tag dynamically set onclick attribute triggers function even I didn't click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have here a link that I set it's `onClick` attribute dynamically but when I run it, it triggers even I did not click the link. Please see the code below

```js
$("a#link1").attr("onClick",testfunction());

function testfunction() {
    alert("on click triggered");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link1">Link</a>
```

Comment: For your case Use quotes to set the attributes As suggested in the below answers. Also consider using addEventListeners https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener to attach event dynamically using JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add quotes to the function, like:

```
$("a#link1").attr("onClick", "testfunction()");
```

Otherwise, it will be interpreted as a call to the function, which immediately triggers it.

```js
$("a#link1").attr("onClick", "testfunction()");

function testfunction() {
    alert("on click triggered");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link1">Link</a>
```

Comment: Actually, I am wrong, sorry. For some reason I was thinking this was a `.on()`, but it's setting the attribute. So it needs to be a string, since that's the attribute value. I just deleted my answer.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro No problem - I actually got messed up too, and thought yours was another solution. Thanks for the message

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the "on" method of the jQuery object to apply the click event?

you can do it like this:

```js
$("a#link1").on("click", testfunction);

function testfunction() {
  alert("on click triggered");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the quotation ("functionName()") on the function

```js
$("a#link1").attr("onClick","testfunction()");

function testfunction() {
    alert("on click triggered");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link1">Link</a>
```